# EF6 table per hierarchy, with unique index on derived property

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework

So I have a table-per-hierarchy inheritance model in Entity Framework code-first, and I'd like to set a unique index constraint on one of the derived properties. Currently it looks something like this:

```
public abstract class BaseObj { ...shared props }

public class DerivedObj : BaseObj { ...more props }

public class AnotherObj : BaseObj {

    [Index(IsUnique = true)]
    public int Prop { get; set; }
}
```

If i try to insert any `DerivedObj` it fails for everything after the first one because of the index matching the previous null entry.

I know this is possible in SQL with a with a filtered index (either just allowing duplicate nulls, or by checking the EF discriminator column) but how could I go about setting this up without manual intervention for database migrations in the future?

Related: [Creating a UNIQUE Filtered Index for NULL values on Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27555538/creating-a-unique-filtered-index-for-null-values-on-entity-framework)

I'm also not scared to poke around with the internals of EF or using unsupported methods to achieve this if someone can point me in the right direction